# Login to Domino server using angularjs is not returning DomAuthSessId

Tags: angularjs, xpages, lotus-domino

I am trying to login to domino server using angularjs, its returning 200 ok but when preview the response its a web page itself. Please see the below code

```
$http({url: 'pathtodb/names.nsf?login',

            data: {
                'username': nm,
                'password': ps
            },
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
                'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest'
            },
            sync : true,
            handleAs : "text",
            'redirectto': 'https://pathtodb/$icon'
        })
        .then(function(response) {
                    console.log(response);
                    //var documentId=(response.headers('Location')).split('unid/')[1];
                    //console.log(documentId);
                    //$scope.forms.modPropForm['@unid']=documentId;
                });
```

Please let me know the correct way, i don't want to use the dojo code.

this is the response i am getting;

```
{data: "<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Trans…="submit" value=""></div></form>↵</body>↵</html>↵", status: 200, headers: ƒ, config: {…}, statusText: "OK"}
```

Comment: Did you try to add the redirectTo to the data section? When you dissect the login form you will see that this is a hidden field that gets posted too. Also when SSO is configured the headers are different

Comment: i tried adding the redirectTo in the data section still no luck, what will be the headers if SSO is configured?

Comment: LTPAToken is the cookie you are looking for. But you should see them

Answer (score 1):

Is the resulting page a login form? Then something with the Authentication went wrong. Status 200 is returned even if the authentication did not succeed.
 If its not the login form, then it you should be ok. If the cookies from domino are set to be http only, you can't check them in your JS code.

Answer (score 0):

I think the response is the Login form, as umeli suggests. Domino returns a status 200 for this. If you're expecting JSON back, then a safe way to check whether the login worked is if the response data starts with a "<". If you're expecting HTML back, or "<" isn't a good indicator, then you could check to see if there's an input field called "password".

I've done this and have had success, but I sent the credentials like this :

```
$http({
url: ("mystuff.thing/db.nsf/xpage.xsp"),
    method: "POST",
    headers: {'Authorization': 'Basic ' + btoa(authModel.userName + ':' + authModel.pwd),  'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8'},
    data: JSON.stringify(result)
})
.then(function(response) { etc .. })
```

That is: base64-encode the authentication info (javascript's btoa function) and send it as part of the header.